# Reliable URL requests iOS?

Tags: ios

I am about to make an iOS POS system, with a web-based backend / dashboard. So, i need to transfer a lot of data from the iOS device to the website via URL-Post requests, transfering in a JSON format.

However, my question is, how do i do this RELIABLY - so i am sure my data is backed up and nothing is lost? i was thinking of making a URL each single time a transaction is made, since by law i need to track each transaction individually.

So each time a transaction is made, i will make a new thread on the iOS device and upload (so i don't block useage of the device while it is uploading).

However, what do i do if it fails? Is there any sort of system i can use that ensures my data is backed up? i was thinking that this problem has been solved before so instead of trying to solve it ground-up myself, i was hoping to get help.

So - how do you reliably make URL requests?

Comment: It's not about how you send them. It's about the way you handle failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reliably make URL calls by checking that you get an expected valid response, and if you don't then it can act accordingly.

Checksum the data (e.g. SHA, etc) in the app and send that checksum with the data. Your web backend can then apply the same checksum logic to the data it received and if it does not match the app's checksum - it knows something has gone wrong with the data.

e.g. When you POST to your web backend, the backend should check the integrity of the data and only if everything is OK should it return a successful response. Otherwise it should return an error response.

When your iOS app receives an OK, it knows everything is good and can carry on as normal. If it get's anything else, i.e. an error response, or a timeout - it can save the data locally and try sending again a short while later.

If the iOS app fails to send the data after a set number of times, an alert can be logged.

If the web backend sends an error response, the web backend should log this and perhaps show alerts in the backend admin interface.

Comment: Sure but your apps (iOS side and web server side) should both understand the data they're dealing with, so comparing checksums of the JSON payload is a sensible way of ensuring data payload integrity with the apps. (Rather than solely relying on the current transport mechanism, HTTP or otherwise.)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use Alamofire and a function to send the data.  Then if (when) the send fails, reload the function (makes a continuous loop until internet is back).

However, you need an 'end game' for things, no matter what you do - always put a counter or other mechanism (a small timer after some loops, etc.) in such a loop to be sure it will eventually give up and go to some error message to the user (like "Can't deliver the data - try again").

Rereading your question, I see it is more of a question of backup or 'reliability' than internet failure.......

You can always make some sort of "Transaction OK" come back from the server (to get really fancy, you can send a specially coded number from the phone and then expect that as part of the server response).

It really depends on what sort of failure rate you expect (with mobile, you should always expect some, so I think you are on the right track!) and if a 'simple' retry will work or you need more grandiose plans.

Comment: but how do you handle it if it fails? what do you do as "end game"? I need 100% reliability, but really can't figure out how to achieve it, but i was thinking that other people must have solved this issue. Every POS system has this issue i think.

Comment: and yea, it is more a "backup" question. really have a hard time figuring it out. i know i can expect some requests to fail, and in maybe 90% of the cases, a simple re-try will come through.

But what if the server is down for hours? What if internet connection is lost in half a day in the shop? how would i handle this, since i need to upload on a transaction-basis

Comment: if the server is down for hours, you have a MUCH bigger problem on your hands!.  In severe cases, you need to store the transactions locally (make a local 'stack') and then when you are ready to send, pull the first one from that stack and run that transaction.

Comment: In the most "critical" of situations, your app could simply say "SYSTEM DOWN" and the vendor would have to call in the transaction (that is how it has been for years....)

Comment: Aim to always have of a 2nd completely separate way of getting the data, in case the primary method became unavailable. e.g. If sending JSON via HTTP goes down, a 2nd method could be for the iOS app to offer the ability to email the data or save to Dropbox. That data can then be picked up as a file and loaded into the backend system manually. (A worst-case scenario and you wouldn't want to do that all the time, but it's great for providing an absolute backup to the normal method. Whether issues at the web backend or the iOS app losing network access completely - your till app can still trade.)